# How to blow open secret hole in Brume Tower if I ran out of explosive carrying enemies?

Tags: ps3, dark-souls-2

In Brume Tower, after the foyer bonfire, I was helping somebody as a phantom and I saw a hole in the wall after the first fume sorcerer that wasn't there in my world.

My research seems to indicate that the only way to open this hole is by exploding a barrel-carrier near it.  But all my barrel-carriers are dead beyond their respawning limits.

Can anyone confirm if there is any/no other way to open this hole?   Am I wasting my time trying to get the big demon guy to break it open with his hammer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual question is:

**Can I open this hole if I have exhausted the spawn limit of explosive carrying enemies?**

Your initial premise is incorrect.  You can no longer truly exhaust enemies.  By joining the [Company of Champions](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Company+of+Champions) covenant, most enemies<sup>*</sup> will have unlimited respawn.

Join this covenant, blown up the wall, and leave the covenant if you do not like the increased difficulty.

<sup>*</sup>: there are specific special enemies that do not respawn:

> Joining this covenant will give all non-special enemies unlimited
>   spawns for the duration you're in the covenant (special enemies such
>   as the Aldia Warlock in Shrine of Amana or the necromancers in
>   Huntsman's Copse will not respawn). Once you leave, all enemies will
>   return to the spawning condition they had before you joined.

Comment: The covenant idea isn't bad.. I had forgotten about it.   I like that better than burning a whatchamacallit to reset the area.

Comment: lol, a bonfire ascetic :)  And generally, you do not use those up until you know exactly what you are getting.  You can get some very powerful items much earlier than normal if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. These can only be destroyed by explosions - generally created by explosive barrels.